# If I imported my dataframe in R and can run associate() why is ALL_CORRELATION giving me an error?

Tags: r, correlation

All I have is a simple dataframe with 27 columns and 100 rows

I continue to get the following error although the simple line of code works with other example of imported data from class?

> all_correlations(MDEFAULT,sorted="strength")
> Error in all_correlations(MDEFAULT, sorted = "strength") :
> This function only accepts data frames. MDEFAULT is a spec_tbl_df
> This function only accepts data frames. MDEFAULT is a tbl_df
> This function only accepts data frames. MDEFAULT is a tbl
> This function only accepts data frames. MDEFAULT is a data.frame

Description:df [100 x 27]

Answer (score 0):

After reading  the error message im guessing the problem is your data are in tbl_df format, a tibble its similar but not identical a data frame format whose function are requering specifically.

Try to simply

```
your_data <- as.data.frame(your_data)
```

Before runing associate()

Like i said, thats a guess. Your question hasnt enough information.